# Out of position/place?

Tags: american-english, british-english

These chairs are out of place/position.

Which one is correct? I feel like i haven't heard anyone use out of postion for anything other than football or when talking to a person, not an inanimate object though.

Can they both be used here?

Answer (score 1):

I think both of them are proper.

Let me give you some examples.

First, out of place means that "not comfortable in or not suitable for a 
situation"  &  "not in the proper place".

The picture looks out of place here.

---

Then, let's take a look at out of position.

In addition to your thought, it means that "not in the correct place".

She wouldn’t tolerate a single spoon, fork, or napkin that was out of position.

-From. Mcmillan Dictionary

---

In conclusion , I think "out of place" is more common when you say that something is misplaced.

Comment: You could use "out of place" for the silverware example, but you can't use "out of position" for the awkward picture.